# JavaScript force UTF-8 encoding

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8

I found this article: http://ecmanaut.blogspot.ro/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html

And many others that recommended this method. But `unescape(encodeURIComponent(srt))` doesn't seem to work for me. I'm trying to convert the contents of a file that I get with `XMLHttpRequest`.

Before using `unescape(encodeURIComponent(srt))` the unicode characters show as "?", after the conversion, all unicode characters show as "ï¿½". So I'm to assume that the conversion failed.

The file itself is encoded with ANSI.

Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9g6zkmof/1/

I need this to work in pure javascript.

**If you are having the same issue with subtitles from OpenSubtitles, please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293926/javascript-force-utf-8-encoding/28298390#28298390).** Otherwise, the selected answer is the correct one.

Thanks

Comment: *"doesn't seem to work for me."* Could you please describe the problem in more detail? Also include the relevant code directly in your question.

Comment: Encoded with ANSI *what*? If the server returns the correct `charset` information, the text will be decoded correctly for you. Anything else client-side is a work-around for a broken server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, it is not encoded in UTF-8:

```
var path = 'http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/filead/src-api/vrf-bfafe1c11f/sid-85k8neb5gpmo3npqoog00t6c64/1954590765.srt'
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", path, false);
xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1');
xhr.send();
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9g6zkmof/2/)**

Comment: This works! But I'm guessing that "iso-8859-1" will not decode all the subtitles on opensubtitles correctly, right?

Would there be a way to decode any files downloaded from opensubtitles correctly?

Comment: The problem is that opensubtitles does not supply a correct `Content-Type`, as the url supplied is meant to be downloaded, so assuming files are multiple encodings, it is a guessing game

Answer (score 0):

I sent an email to the webmaster at OpenSubtitles, he replied by directing me to one of his posts from just 4 days ago:

http://forum.opensubtitles.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=14992&p=30697#p30697

Now you can request any subtitle in whatever encoding you want and the server will use `iconv()` to encode it. This is not 100% because `iconv()` can also fail, but is the best case scenario.

So this link:

`http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/filead/src-api/vrf-bfafe1c11f/sid-85k8neb5gpmo3npqoog00t6c64/1954590765.srt`

now becomes:

`http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/subencoding-utf8/file/1954590765`

and you receive a subtitle file encoded in UTF-8.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9g6zkmof/6/)